pfSense routing issues
Ive got a routing issue on my pfSense box that shows the response to a ping request being routed to a IP in a separate subnet/vlan.
10:25:13.239238 IP 10.2.0.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 9374, seq 15401, length 9
10:25:13.369458 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.20.21: ICMP echo reply, id 9374, seq 15401, length 9

I've recently added a wireguard VPN to the box, and assigned it an interface (VPN). The internet gateway is set to send a health check to 8.8.8.8, its reporting down based on 100% packet loss based on this routing issue.
I also believe that I am seeing:

the response come through the WAN interface and not the VPN interface.
the packet doesnt appear to have the reply-to flag (cant find anywhere to set this from the IG)
the wireguard tunnel remains active throughout
the VPN provider is PRotonVPN

I cant explain why this would happen, and have checked

Nat rules
UPNP
Firewall rules
Interface

Why would a ping response not return to its point of origin?

It doesn't return to the point of origin as the destination address doesn't match the source address. I know you have checked the NAT rules but this does look like a NAT problem. Is the ping supposed to go via wireguard? If so could it be that the remote end of the wireguard is doing NAT?

You my friend are an absolute genius. I had NAT turned off with the the config, however I VPN Accelerator was switched on. The feature balances over a number of IP's and must loose headers for the response or return from an alternative IP entirely. Legend

Now, can only icarus post this as an answer or can the OP?

@icarus definitely gets the credit. I've got the details so I'll post it in the am

Post the details as a self answer, I know less than you about your setup, so even if I changed my comment into an answer it would be less useful, and the the point of stack exchange is to have high quality answers (to train AI?). If you feel answers I give are good then feel free to search out others and vote them up. If you think they are bad then downvote them. I appreciate all the votes, both up and down, as well as comments on the answers I give.
